# append values with both single and double quotes to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to append a value from the result data set to a `input` that may have any special character like `*^&$#>,'"` etc. The problem is that I am not able to append the entire `var` into the `input`.

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/HzcHw/1/). What is the thing that I have missed out in it?

Cant I do this without using `.find` and `.append` like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/HzcHw/2/)?

Comment: I am concatinating a `var`, and in the end I am appending this to some div . Just see a sample case below. 

`uques += "<span style='width:900px; margin-top:-20px;' class='answer_part quest"  
+ (i + 1) + "' qtype='" + data.sometype+ "' qid='" + data.someid+ "'  
isman='" + data.somevar+ "' que='" + data.somequestion+ ". " + mod + "'>  
<input type='text' maxlength='100' id='" + i + "' class='tb1 validate[required]'  
value='" + textboxanswer + "' ></input>  
<span class='charCount' id='charCount" + i + "'>(" + character + " characters) </span></span>";  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to solve this problem without using `.find` or appending the `var` seperately, I found a simple solution for this. I just need to replace the `single quote` " **'** " with its iso latin code `&#39;` and other special characters with their respective codes and then use that variable in `.html`

```
var something= "this is vicky\"s \"s 's 's \"s \"S";
test=something.replace(/'/g,"&#39;").replace(/"/g,'\\"');
$("#test").html("hey this is <input id='testbox' value='"+test+"'></input>");
```

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/HzcHw/9/)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are concatenating strings, which doesn't take escaping of special characters into account. You should instead set the value with `.val` so that the value is escaped properly. Also, the regex is unnecessary.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test= "this is vicky\"s \"s 's 's \"s \"S";

    alert(test);

    var input = $("<input style='width:700px;' id='testbox'></input>").val(test);

    $("#test").html("hey this is ").append(input);

});
```

See [updated test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzcHw/6/)

Comment: `unescape` is for turning percent-encoded ASCII values into ASCII characters again. Since there are no percent-encoded values here, there's no need to use unescape, it just does _nothing_ here.

Comment: @CBroe or *worse* if there *is* `%` in `something`

Comment: The problem is I have a lot of cases (switch cases) and i am appending variable based on the cases (say radio button, div, p . . .)   
so for textbox too i keep adding up the string and I am concatinating this  variable and in the end I am appending 
it to the div  .    
Just see a sample case below

Comment: @vignesh Just provide a fiddle instead of posting code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I tried so many things finally this worked:

```
var getClinician = row.ClinicianName;
getClinician = getClinician.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

var Clinician = '<td align=""><input type="text" id="txt_Clinician_' + row.ScheduleID + '" value="' + getClinician + '"  />';
```